# how I can check if the email is already exist in authentication firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have this function to create `authentication` in my firebase but the problem is when the user enters an email that already exists my app will stop `com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: The email address is already in use by another account.`
how I can check if the email is already exists in the authentication

```
fun createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        auth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    user.userID = auth.uid!!
                    Log.d("TAG", "${auth.uid}")
                    addUser(user)
                } else {
                    Log.d("userVM" ,task.result.toString())
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FirebaseAuth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(@NonNull email: String, @NonNull password: String)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(kotlin.String,%20kotlin.String)) method:

> Tries to create a new user account with the given email address and password. If successful, it also signs the user into the app.

This means that if you try to create a user that **already** exists, a [FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) will be thrown:

> Thrown when an operation on a FirebaseUser instance couldn't be completed due to a conflict with another existing user.

If a user already exists, you should call another method that only signs in the user which is called
[signInWithEmailAndPassword(@NonNull email: String, @NonNull password: String)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signInWithEmailAndPassword(kotlin.String,%20kotlin.String)):

> Tries to sign in as a user with the given email address and password.

That doesn't try to create the user again. If you want to check if a user already exists, you should add user details in [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) for example, and use my solution from the following post:

- [How to check if a document exist in firestore kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69452299/how-to-check-if-a-document-exist-in-firestore-kotlin/69460539#69460539)

Answer (score 0):

For those using the Pyrebase library in python. This method does not try to create a new user account with the given email address. If the email is not found.

```
    def does_email_exist(email, password="password"):
    try:
        auth = pyre.auth()
        auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
           
         # read message in HTTPError
    except requests.HTTPError as e:         
        error_json = e.args[1]
        error = json.loads(error_json)['error']['message']
        # if account with this email doesn't exist.
        if error == "USER_NOT_FOUND" or error == "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND":
            return False
    return True
```

does_email_exist can trigger the Firebase TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER flag, if it's used too many times.

```
    existing_emails = []
    temp_email = "a@abc.com"

    if temp_email in existing_emails or does_email_exist(temp_email):
        print("Account With Email Already Exists.")

        if temp_email not in existing_emails:
             existing_emails.append(temp_email)
```